# How to link files in Thimble?

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I'm having trouble linking files to eachother. I'm using buttons to do so, although I know `<a href="">` is better. I've tried this:

```
onclick="window.location.href='roadster.html'
```

inside the `<button>` tag. I also tried `href="roadster.html"` but  it didn't work either. So I have one file named index.html and the other being roadster.html.

How can I link them using the editor Thimble?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is thimble some kind of online html editor?

Comment: Yes, it is a free editor from Mozilla

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```
onchange="window.location.href='roadster.html'
```

Comment: It didn't work, I don't know if this will solve it, but after the last ', should I add a " or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<SELECT onchange="window.location.href'roadster.html'
```